# Regex for alphanumeric string with a maximum number of spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need a JS regex to match a string based only on a known first and last sub-string and number of spaces - and I don't care about the length or the nature of what is between the first and last sub-strings (other than the exact number of spaces).

The following is a possible start string (from which I get the first and last sub-strings and the number of spaces):

`cat apple dog mouse`

From this, I now know the string starts with `cat`, ends with `mouse` and contains exactly 3 spaces (they could be be anywhere between the ends, but they will not be consecutive).

The string I need to match against might be:

`catfish mouse mouse dormouse mouse mouse`

or `cat mouse mouse mouse mouse mouse`

So, what I need to match would be, in the first case `catfish mouse mouse dormouse`, and in the second case `cat mouse mouse mouse` - in both cases a string starting with `cat`, ending with `mouse` and containing exactly 3 spaces.  At the moment, all my attempts match the entire sample string above, not just from `cat` to the third `mouse`.  Here is my latest failure:

`cat(?:(?![\s]{4,}).*)mouse`

I have a strong suspicion I'm overthinking this - but thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a regex without look aheads do do this.

**Example**

```
\bcat(?:[^\s]*\s){3}[^\s]*mouse\b
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zVeUAz/2)

---

**What it does?**

- `\b` Matches a word boundary. This ensures that it doesn't match strings that end as `mousexyz`
- `cat` Matches `cat` at the start of the string
- `(?:[^\s]*\s){3}`

  - `[^\s]*` Matches anything other than a space. So this one matches a single word and the following `\s` matches the space after the word.
  - `{3}` Makes sure that the *single word with space* is repeated 3 times.
- `[^\s]*` Matches any character other than space after the 3 spaces.
- `mouse` Matches mouse at the end of the string

---

**Why doesn't `cat(?:(?![\s]{4,}).*)mouse` work?**`

- `(?![\s]{4,})` This negative lookahead, will check if `cat`  is not *immediately* followed by 4 spaces. Which is true so it matches all the input strings.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  The problem is that the first and last characters of the match might be spaces.  So, it would need to match `cat mouse mouse mouse` as well.

Comment: @sideroxylon Why don't you trim the string?

Comment: because the starting `cat` and `mouse` are part of the match, so the spaces are not at the ends.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood that part. Will update the answer. Do you want to include those spaces also in the match?

Comment: Yes, the entire string from cat -> mouse (with 3 spaces) needs to be matched and replaced.  Thanks!

Comment: @sideroxylon I have updated my answer. Please check if meets your requirements.

Comment: That's the one!  Beautifully simple.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer allows for consecutive spaces

Comment: @Dal Yes, if there are two consecutive spaces, they are counted as two spaces. I assumed that is how op wanted given the fact that in the first example, we are counting spaces and not words after the `cat`. Even if it is to be treated as single, its easy by adding a `+` quantifier to the `\s`

Comment: Oh but op said no consecutive spaces here 
" From this, I now know the string starts with cat, ends with mouse and contains exactly 3 spaces (they could be be anywhere between the ends, but they will not be consecutive)."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not anywhere near as good at regex as nu11p01n73R is but I tried for fun:

```
/cat[^\s]*(\s[^\s]+){2}\s[^\s]*?mouse/
```

It is ugly but it worked when I tested it

looks for 'cat'

then runs through any non whitespace

do twice
{

then looks for a space

then looks for at least one char of non whitespace

}

then runs through any non whitespace

until it finds mouse